# Ansible win_package doesn't work with brackets in registy variable

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to uninstall application by using product_id. I think the reason may be only one thing - brackets, because with other applications without brackets in registry variables it works pretty fine. How can i remove there brackets or somethink to solve this?
[This works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uRcN.png) [but not this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrxKn.png)

```
- name: Uninstalling Total Commander IT Edition
win_package:
  product_id: '{7E25FC96-BC45-4D1C-AA24-2D147AD2B8D0}_is1'
  state: absent
  arguments: /7
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just grab the path, remove the brackets and put it back in.

```
- name: Obtain IT Editions's uninstall string for edit
  win_reg_stat:
    path: 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7E25FC96-BC45-4D1C-AA24-2D147AD2B8D0}_is1'
    name: UninstallString
  register: uninst_str_IT
- name: Write properly path 
  win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7E25FC96-BC45-4D1C-AA24-2D147AD2B8D0}_is1
    name: UninstallString
    data: "{{uninst_str_IT.value | regex_replace ('\"', '')}}"
- name: Uninstalling Total Commander IT Edition
  win_package:
    product_id: '{7E25FC96-BC45-4D1C-AA24-2D147AD2B8D0}_is1'
    arguments: /SILENT
    state: absent
```